# jquery .class hover function.. apply styling to individual elements, not group

Tags: jquery, hover, css

I have the following code:

```
var shadow = "#FF00FF 0 50px 90px inset";

$('#element').find('a.thumbnail').hover(function() {
     $(this).css({ '-webkit-box-shadow': shadow, '-moz-box-shadow': shadow, '-khtml-box-shadow': shadow, 'box-shadow': shadow});
},
function(){
     $(this).css({'background-color': 'transparent', '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none', '-moz-box-shadow': 'none', '-khtml-box-shadow': 'none', 'box-shadow': 'none'});
});
```

But the problem is that the box-shadow is applied to the entire group of .thumbnails .. So the first thumbnail div has a darker color than the last thumbnail div (box shadow)..

Whilst what I am trying to achieve is the shadow effect applied only to the hovered thumbnail.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit: markup looks like this:**

```
<div id="element">

<a class="thumbnail" href="xxx">
    <img src="" />
    <span>Title</span>
    <div class="thumbnail_description">Description</div>
</a>

*** Repeat ***

</div>
```

.thumbnail is display:block

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: Looking at the code you post you are missing }); at the last line. I can't see the second function closing and hover paranthesis closing.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error when I added the question here. I have also added the markup.

Comment: There's no #element in your markups

Comment: Sorry, the .thumbnail elements are in #element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should work.
[Here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/nTWxy/) of your own code and you can see that it works.
Maybe you had an error somewhere else in the page or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even using javascript? You're just adding shadows to the `<a>` tag on hover right

In your CSS file:

```
a.thumbnail:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: #FF00FF 0 50px 90px inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: #FF00FF 0 50px 90px inset;
    .... etc
}
```

Edit, here's the jQuery way of doing it from your example, which FYI, is madness.

```
$('a.thumbnail', '#element').hover(function() {
     $(this).css({ '-webkit-box-shadow': shadow, '-moz-box-shadow': shadow, '-khtml-box-shadow': shadow, 'box-shadow': shadow});
},
function(){
     $(this).css({'background-color': 'transparent', '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none', '-moz-box-shadow': 'none', '-khtml-box-shadow': 'none', 'box-shadow': 'none'});
});
```

Comment: No, can't do it that way. Hard to explain but due to certain structures I cannot simply use CSS declarations, suffice to say.

Comment: Well you need to explain it better then. Because what it looks like is your code attempt is just adding styles when you hover over an anchor tag.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it does. I am constrained by a plugin structure for a web editing program, in that I cannot add the css itself, but only use javascript to do so.

Comment: If you can add javascript, you should be able to add CSS?

Comment: No, not in this specific instance.

Comment: Makes no sense to be honest. Updated question with jQuery way.

Comment: That's not the jQuery-way, the idea in the question should work too.

Comment: Seems to work for some reason, thanks! And thanks for answering the question, even though it made no sense ;)